# Game of Life Continuation Issues

Tags: javascript, rows, conways-game-of-life

I'm having a problem with my Game of Life code. It seems to only show the first pattern of dead/alive cells, but does not go on to turn others into dead or alive cells, but instead turns all of them dead, then one alive in the uppermost left hand corner, then all dead again. How can I make it so the cells become dead or alive properly?

```js
"use strict";

window.onload=function()
{
 var gameBoardArray;
 var i;
 var j;
 var tempArray;

 gameBoardArray=create2dArray(10, 10, getDeadValue());
 tempArray=copy2dArray(gameBoardArray);
 createGameBoard(document.getElementById("gameBoard"), gameBoardArray);
 createFirstGeneration(gameBoardArray);

 for(i = 0; i < gameBoardArray.length; i++)
 {
  for(j = 0; j < gameBoardArray[i].length; j++)
  {
   if(gameBoardArray[i][j] === getLiveValue())
   {

    document.getElementById('r' + i + 'c' + j).style.backgroundColor = getLiveColor();

   }

   else
   {

    document.getElementById('r' + i + 'c' + j).style.backgroundColor = getDeadColor();
   }
  }
 }
 window.setInterval( function()
 {
  applyRules(gameBoardArray, tempArray);
 }, 1000);
};

function trim(data)
{
 var start;
 var whitespace;
 var end;
 var result;

 if(typeof data==="string")
  {
   whitespace=" \n\r\t\f";
   start=0;
 }

 else
 {
  result=data;
 }

 while((start<data.length)&&(whitespace.indexOf(data.charAt(start))))
 {
  start=start+1;
 };
 end=data.length-1;

 while((end>=0)&&(whitespace.indexOf(data.charAt(end))))
 {
  end=end-1;
 };

 if(end<start)
 {
  result="";
 }
 else
 {
  result=data.substring(1+start,end);
 }
  return result;
};

function createHTMLElement(elementType, id, classInfo, content)
{
 if(elementType===null)
 {
  elementType="";
 };

 trim(elementType);

 if(id===null)
 {
  id="";
 }

 trim(id);

 if(id.length>0)
 {
  id=" "+"id="+'"'+id+'"'+" ";
 };

 if(classInfo===null)
 {
  classInfo="";
 }

 trim(classInfo);

 if(classInfo.length>0)
 {
  classInfo=" "+ "class="+'"'+classInfo+'"';
 }

 if(content===null)
 {
  content="";
 };

 trim(content);

 return '<' +elementType +
 id + classInfo +
 '>' + content +
 '</' + elementType + '>';
};

function getDeadValue()
{
 return 0;
};

function getLiveValue()
{
 return 1;
};

function isAlive(cell)
{
 if(cell===getDeadValue())
 {
  return cell==getDeadValue();
 }

 else
 {
  return cell==getDeadValue();
 }
};

function getLiveColor()
{
 return "green";
}

function getDeadColor()
{
 return "red";
}

function isInArray(array2d, row, col)
{
 if(row >= 0 && row < array2d.length && col >= 0 && col < array2d.length)
 {
  return true;
 }
 else
 {
  return false;
 }
}

function create2dArray(rows, columns, initialValue)

{
 var array2d;
 var i;
 var j;

 array2d = new Array(rows);

 for(i = 0; i < array2d.length; i++)
 {
  array2d[i] = new Array(columns);
  for(j = 0; j < array2d[i].length; j++)
  {
   array2d[i][j] = initialValue;
  }

 }
 return array2d;
}

function copy2dArray(array)
{

 var i;
 var j;
 var result;

 result = new Array(array.length);

 for(i = 0; i < result.length; i++)

 {

  result[i] = new Array(array[i].length);

  for(j = 0; j < result[i].length; j++)
  {
   result[i][j] = array[i][j];
  }
 }
 return result;
}

function createGameBoard(containerElement, array2d)
{
 var classInfo;
 var count;
 var i;
 var innerHTML;
 var j;

 innerHTML = "";
 count = 0;

 for(i = 0; i < array2d.length; i++)
 {

  if(i === 0)
  {
   classInfo = 'cell firstRow newRow';
  }

  else
  {
   classInfo = 'cell newRow';
  }

  for(j = 0; j < array2d[i].length; j++)
  {
   if(i === 0 && j === array2d[i].length - 1)
   {
    classInfo = 'cell firstRow lastColumn';
   }

   if(i !== 0 && j === array2d[i].length - 1)
   {
    classInfo = 'cell lastColumn';
   }

   innerHTML = innerHTML + createHTMLElement('div', 'r' + i + 'c' + j, classInfo, null);

   if(i === 0)
   {
    classInfo = 'cell firstRow';
   }

   else
   {
    classInfo = 'cell';
   }

   count = count + 1;
  }
 }
 containerElement.innerHTML = innerHTML;
}

function createFirstGeneration(array2d)
{
 var i;
 var j;
 var k;
 var row;
 var col;

 for(i=0; i<array2d.length; i++)
 for(j=0; j<array2d[i].length; j++)
 {
  if(i===j||i==j||(i+j)%5===0)
  {
   array2d[i][j]=getLiveValue();
  }
 }
}

function countLivingNeighborsOf(array2d, row, col)
{

 var count;

 count = 0;

 if(isInArray(array2d, row + 1, col) && isAlive(array2d[row + 1][col]))
 {
  count = count + 1;
 }

 if(isInArray(array2d, row - 1, col) && isAlive(array2d[row - 1][col]))
 {
  count = count + 1;
 }

 if(isInArray(array2d, row, col + 1) && isAlive(array2d[row][col + 1]))
 {
  count = count + 1;
 }

 if(isInArray(array2d, row, col - 1) && isAlive(array2d[row][col - 1]))
 {
  count = count + 1;
 }

 if(isInArray(array2d, row + 1, col + 1) && isAlive(array2d[row + 1][col + 1]))
 {
  count = count + 1;
 }

 if(isInArray(array2d, row - 1, col - 1) && isAlive(array2d[row - 1][col - 1]))
 {
  count = count + 1;
 }

 if(isInArray(array2d, row - 1, col + 1) && isAlive(array2d[row - 1][col + 1]))
 {
  count = count + 1;
 }

 if(isInArray(array2d, row + 1, col - 1) && isAlive(array2d[row + 1][col - 1]))
 {
  count = count + 1;
 }

 return count;
}

function applyRules(array2d, tmpArray)
{
 var i;
 var j;

 for(i = 0; i < array2d.length; i++)
 {
  for(j = 0; j < array2d[i].length; j++)
  {
   tmpArray[i][j] = countLivingNeighborsOf(array2d, i, j);
  }
 }

 for(i = 0; i < array2d.length; i++)
 {

  for(j = 0; j < array2d[i].length; j++)
  {
   if(tmpArray[i][j] < 2)
   {
    array2d[i][j] = 0;
   }

   if(tmpArray[i][j] > 3)
   {
    array2d[i][j] = 0;
   }

   if(tmpArray[i][j] === 3)
   {
    array2d[i][j] = 1;
   }

   if(tmpArray[i][j] === 1)
   {
    document.getElementById('r' + i + 'c' + j).style.backgroundColor = getLiveColor();
   }

   else
   {
    document.getElementById('r' + i + 'c' + j).style.backgroundColor = getDeadColor();
   }
  }
 }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title> Game of Life </title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8"/>
<script src="GameOfLife.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<style type="text/css">

{
border : 0;
margin : 0;
padding : 0;
}

body
{
font-family : "Times New Roman", serif;
font-size : 12pt;
}

#page
{
margin:auto;
}

.cell
{
border-left: 1px solid black;
border-bottom: 1px solid black;
float: left;
height: .5em;
width: .5em;
}

.newRow
{
border-left: 1px solid black;
clear: left;
}

.firstRow
{
border-top: 1px solid black;
}

.lastColumn
{
border-right: 1px solid black;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="page">
<div id="gameBoard">
</div> <!-- gameBoard -->
</div> <!-- page -->
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how I usually implement the game of life in JavaScript:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("universe");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

var width = canvas.width;
var height = canvas.height;

var size = 2;
var cell = size - 1;

var rows = Math.floor(height / size);
var cols = Math.floor(width / size);

var bottom = rows - 1;
var right = cols - 1;

var universe = new Array(cols);

for (var x = 0; x < cols; x++) {
  var col = new Array(rows);
  for (var y = 0; y < rows; y++)
    col[y] = false;
  universe[x] = col;
}

var cx = Math.floor(cols / 2);
var cy = Math.floor(rows / 2);
var ct = cy - 1;

universe[cx][cy] = true;
universe[cx][ct] = true;
universe[cx][cy + 1] = true;
universe[cx - 1][cy] = true;
universe[cx + 1][ct] = true;

animate();

function drawCell(x, y) {
  context.fillRect(size * x + 1, size * y + 1, cell, cell);
}

function drawUniverse() {
  context.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
  for (var x = 0; x < cols; x++)
    for (var y = 0; y < rows; y++)
      if (universe[x][y]) drawCell(x, y);
}

function animate() {
  setTimeout(animate, 125);
  drawUniverse();
  updateUniverse();
}

function updateUniverse() {
  var newUniverse = new Array(cols);

  for (var x = 0; x < cols; x++) {
    var col = new Array(rows);

    for (var y = 0; y < rows; y++) {
      var l = x > 0 ? x - 1 : right;
      var r = x < right ? x + 1 : 0;
      var t = y > 0 ? y - 1 : bottom;
      var b = y < bottom ? y + 1 : 0;

      var neighbors = [ universe[l][t], universe[x][t], universe[r][t]
                      , universe[l][y],                 universe[r][y]
                      , universe[l][b], universe[x][b], universe[r][b] ];

      var count = 0;
      for (var i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        if (neighbors[i]) count++;

      var self = universe[x][y];

      col[y] = count === 3 || self && count === 2;
    }

    newUniverse[x] = col;
  }

  universe = newUniverse;
}
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 1px solid #000000;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="universe" width="559" height="179"></canvas>
```

Hope this helps.